# Linux (CentOS) Delete cronjob from apache

Tags: php, apache, cron

I'm reciving tons of emails with a problem related to a cronJob:

```
Return-Path: <root@******>
Received: (qmail 25143 invoked by uid 502); 22 Feb 2015 13:13:01 +0100
Date: 22 Feb 2015 13:13:01 +0100
Message-ID: <*******.****.qmail@*******
From: root@****** (Cron Daemon)
To: apache@*******
Subject: Cron <apache@*****> /var/www/vhosts/*****.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/wordpress-creation-kit-api/assets/js/ckeditor/plugins/magicline/images/hidpi/1.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=es_ES>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=apache>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=apache>

/bin/sh: /var/www/vhosts/*****.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/wordpress-creation-kit-api/assets/js/ckeditor/plugins/magicline/images/hidpi/1.sh: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

I know uid 502 is apache and I've checked cron jobs for that user:

```
[root@*** ~]# crontab -u apache -l

* * * * * /var/www/vhosts/*****.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wck-custom-f                                                       ields-and-custom-post-types-creator/wordpress-creation-kit-api/assets/js/ckedito                                                       r/plugins/magicline/images/hidpi/1.sh

* * * * * /var/www/vhosts/*****.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wck-custom-f                                                       ields-and-custom-post-types-creator/wordpress-creation-kit-api/assets/js/ckedito                                                       r/plugins/magicline/images/hidpi/1.sh
```

So, how can I delete this cron jobs?

Comment: Edit the crontab with `crontab -u apache -e`?

Comment: in my case crontab -u apache -r but it worked, thanks!